# Jquery cannot recognize table id from variable

Tags: jquery, datatable

Have been struggling with JQuery datatable. https://datatables.net/

The .js and bootstrap links and files are correct because whole JQuery pagination datatable works if the table and its content is inside div.

The script code is follow:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "pagingType": "full_numbers"
    } );
});
```

Then there is:

```
function generateTable(){
var table = "<table id='example' class='display' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>"
```

after that, the users table information is read in with Json and put to table as

```
table +=
```

Lastly, the whole table variable is put to div:

```
$("#myDiv").append($(table));
```

! The function does not recognize id='example' !
What could be changed so, It can recognize ?

Like It was said, the data table with CSS generates correctly if data is put directly to div.

Thanks

Made an alltogether separate function

```
function dataTable() {
$('#example').DataTable( {
        "pagingType": "full_numbers"
    } );
}
```

and called it out after generateTable() and did not work.

Comment: Is the page triggering "ready" before it loads the Json? Things are asynchronous... Place a few `console.log("fetching json");` and `console.log("document ready");` to see which order it runs.

Comment: The log shows, that the fetching json is last.
Table head columns are given so the table structure should be printed out no matter what.

Comment: Why don't you call DataTable after you are done loading the div?
Anything else showing on console?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
function generateTable(data){
     if(data.lenght > 0){
       var table = "<table id='example' class='display' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>";
       //*** the rest of the code / use table += data... ***
       table += "</table>"; //close the element to make it a valid element!
     }
     else { 
       table = <table id='example' class='display' style="display:none;"></table>"; //so it is a valid element
     }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
     $.getJSON( "your call" )
       .done(function( json ) {
           generateTable(json);//when the document is ready, it should be call so it can be append...
       })
      .fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
          generateTable("");//when the document is ready, it should be call so it can be append...
     });

     $("#myDiv").append($(table)); // then you append it

     //now you can use it, because now is part of the DOM.
     $('#example').DataTable( {
         "pagingType": "full_numbers"
     } );
});
```

Like that it will create the table after json is returned or an empty table if it isn't. Hope it helps you.

Comment: When I use call out generateTable function there, then the JSON is not read in. It is to mention that before building this, I used <table class='zui-table'> table style in variable and everything worked.
Have debugged it from every angle and the id in variable is not legid.

Comment: Also, the cellspacing and width change gives affect in table variable.

Comment: The idea is good, but the problem is loading the table plug-in from id.

Comment: well in that case, the problem might be that the table is being append into the DOM you could then try `$(document).find("#example").DataTable({"pagingType": "full_numbers"});` or better `$("#myDiv").find("#example").DataTable({"pagingType": "full_numbers"});` and because the id should be unique it should only find your table if it exist.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your help.
Managed to get the solution with your ideas.

It was all about synchronization and the example table was put to div after document.ready(function) so I could not have loaded the correct dataTable base.

So, I called out the

```
function dataTable() {
$('#example').DataTable( {
        "pagingType": "full_numbers"
    } );
}
```

from

```
function generateTable(){
```

after the

```
$("#myDiv").append($(table));
dataTable();
```